# Use other's credit card to pay for visa fee

Tags: credit-card, hong-kong

My friend is applying for Hong Kong visa and in the application form he needs to fill in credit card info (and provide cardholder's signature) to pay for the processing fee. However he doesn't have one currently and he would like to use mine. I want to reject his request, for obvious risk of leaking my personal info. Can I tell him that the bank will reject the transaction because the cardholder is not the visa applicant, and thus involves risk of fraud? Is there a general policy applicable to most banks?

Comment: "I'm sorry, but I am not comfortable using my credit card to pay your visa fees."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I tell him that the bank will reject the transaction because the
>   cardholder is not the visa applicant, and thus involves risk of fraud?
>   Is there a general policy applicable to most banks?

In general a bank won't reject the transaction just because the name on the card doesn't match the name of the person the purchase is for.

There is a mismatch of the name on the card and purchaser every time a parent lets their child use their card to pay for tuition, school books, or camp.

There is also a mismatch every time there is a card with a persons full name, but they go with a nickname.

Not to mention when two people in the household are married.

Forms that allow credit/debit card purchases do ask for the name on the card. This is needed for verification purposes. The bank never sees the rest of information on the form. They only see name, card number, and CVV.

If you don't want your friend to use your card, then just say you are uncomfortable doing so.